# Why does the boost lib have external linkage, not internal? (Best practice of linkage for header-only)

Tags: c++, boost, linkage

Boost library defines functions [as following style](https://github.com/boostorg/format/blob/c1170a6d546b36f9399f3983fad0994e8f946d8f/include/boost/format/parsing.hpp#L58-L63);

```cpp
namespace boost::io::detail {
    template<class Iter, class Facet>
    Iter wrap_scan_notdigit(...) {
        // snip
    }
}
```

To my understanding, the function has external linkage because

- the namespace is on the global scope, not unnamed
- function is not "static" declared

From my experience, the external linkage on the header often causes the ODR violation.
For example, two different translation units could include the different versions; this often happens when you use 3rd-party <del>.so</del> .a (static) libs.

The critical issue of the ODR violation is NDR: compiler/linker doesn't have to emit errors, but it could generate an execution-time bug in the rare case.

The internal linkage can avoid the problem.

So my question is (same as on the title):

- Why is the boost's linkage external, not internal?
- (To be generalized above) How should I set the linkage for my header-only library?

Comment: You don't set any linkage in header-only library. Linkage is something that users of your library have to take care of. If there's any ODR violations because user wants to use different versions of boost library then they are screwed. It can only be resolved by separating the includes into different shared libraries. However, with C++20 modules it is possible to fix it in much simpler manner.

Comment: `inline` is the tool for this job, not `static`, and all function templates are `inline` by default.

Comment: @ALX23z "different versions" - the same issue applies when users include the same version in a TU that has different flags/defines.

Comment: @MilesBudnek... `inline` functions still can participate in linking depending on compilers wishes. `static` / unnamed namespace functions declared in cpp aren't linked.

Comment: @ALX23z Yes, you're right. header.h itself doesn't have linkage, but included tokens by source.cpp has. I just omitted it.

Comment: @MilesBudnek TMU `inline` does *NOT* solve the situation in my question. `inline` does not change its linkage. ODR could be caused by functions which have the same name but different tokens even if inline. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> the external linkage on the header often causes the ODR violation.

Only when the headers are poorly written (or possibly when they are poorly used, if definitions depend on preprocessor directives).

External linkage reduces code bloat, as you need only one copy of each function per program, rather than one copy per translation unit.

> this often happens when you use 3rd-party .so libs.

Library object code should not export symbols from header-only libraries. The point of header-only is that it is available without linking to library object code.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you. It's my mistake (I'm not familiar with Linux). I wanted to write "3rd-party *.a* static libs". Static lib should contain the header-only lib's symbol. So the header-only lib who doesn't case its linkage has risk of  ODR violation as I said.